Which shader to use when baking normals?
I wanted to bake normals from a sculpt onto a lower poly mesh into a texture. Then I found out that the shader used on the source objects affects the resulting normal.
So I tried making a new project, made a plane with a noise texture for a bump map, another with a texture, and tried baking from different shaders from first plane to the second, and got different results:

It appears that Diffuse BSDF's normal map looks most contrasted, Glossy's is smoother, and Principled's is somewhere in between. Enabling coat for Principled produces a fourth result, smoothest of them all.
Roughness settings doesn't appear to change much, but IOR setting on Principled does. I suppose Principled just combines Glossy and Diffuse based on Fresnel with set IOR for this, which is why it looks in between of the two. Changing shadow terminator settings on the source object doesn't affect much either.
Anyway, this all leads me to my question. Which shader should I use when baking normals from? What's the reason for the difference between Glossy and Diffuse? Is it a Blender bug, or there's some actual consideration to make?
